# Button OnClick() Event not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page in which I'm making an addition that requires me to add another button event. In the example below, btnTwo and btnThree fire their OnClick() events and function as they should. Yet when I added btnOne with its associated OnClick() event, it dose not fire the break point I setup for String test. I inspected the page while running the project and noticed that btnTwo and btnThree have an onclick dopostbackwithoptions in the control yet btnOne dose not. Also when clicking btnOne, pageload events do not fire as well. I don't know whats going on with this or what I am doing wrong. Ive also tried doing a clean build on the solution as that was recommended by another online resource but it still dose not function as it should.

Page:

```
<table style="width: 210px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-right: 50px">
            <asp:Button ID="btnOne" runat="server" CssClass="DefaultButton" Width="120px" OnClick="btnOne_Click" />
        </td>
        <td style="padding-right: 50px">
            <asp:Button ID="btnTwo" runat="server" ValidationGroup="QtyGroup" CssClass="DefaultButton" Width="90px" OnClick="btnTwo_click" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnThree" runat="server" CssClass="DefaultButton" Width="90px" OnClick="btnThree_click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string test = "";
    }
```

Comment: try setting the AutoPostBack attribute to true in your asp.net code

Comment: I just tried setting up AutoPostBack to true and it did not work. I have also tried wrapping the control in an update panel and that did not work as-well.

Comment: Try without an UpdatePanel and get it working before you try it with an UpdatePanel. UpdatePanel's can really complicate things.

Comment: show the markup that includes the update panel and the aspx control.. what is the mode of your update panel set to it should be `UpdateMode="Conditional"` also try assigning id to table as well I don't see anything like the following for your table `<table id=`

Comment: Initially I did not have an UpdatePanel wrapped on the control, so i figured give it a shot and see if that would resolve my problem. Yet, it didn't so I removed it. I also went into design mode to click on the button to see if it would direct me to the OnClick() event and it did. But for whatever reason when I run the project, btnOne in my example, is the only control with no click event when I inspect it from the browser. So I don't know where to go with this from here.

Comment: what other controls do you have on your aspx page?

Comment: There is a lot going on in the page I am working on as it has various tables, modal popup extenders, etc. What dosent make sense to me is how all the other buttons on the page work and the new one that was just added dose not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am willing to bet your button event is firing, but your debugging is not firing. I have seen this when binding the solution to iis incorrectly. In your event, add some code to update a label and I bet it works. Check your URL. I have seen when my IIS binding is incorrect the url changes from localhost:someport to a dns name. This may cause your debugging break points not to fire.

Comment: I did your suggestion and it works. The label populates with text on button click even though the breakpoints don't fire. Going to spend some time looking over the IIS settings on my solution. Thanks!

Comment: Just looked over IIS and the site binding for the host name was not there. I added the dns name and everything worked including all the breakpoints. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Restart VS and then delete the event name from .aspx page and again create a new event . Some times VS has some problems. It has worked for me sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my post. I tried your recommendation and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the access modifier to `public` and see if that makes any difference.  I've noticed a similar behavior in WPF.

I also noticed that your event handlers for btnTwo and btnThree have lower case `click` in handling method name.  I'm not sure if you typed the code here by hand or copy/pasted it.  Check to make sure that the names match.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my post. The example that I posted was copied from the original solution except I changed the button ID's for to make the post easier to read. The button event handlers for btnTwo and btnThree match their corresponding onclick event in the code-behind and function as they should. So, I tried changing the access modifier to public and doing a clean build on the solution and btnOne still dose not work. It dose not even trigger the breakpoints I have on the page load events either.

Answer (score 1):

Have you copied this method from other page/application ? if yes then it will not work, So you need to delete the event and event name assigned to the button then go to design and go to button even properties go to onClick event double click next to it, it will generate event and it automatically assigns event name to the button. this should work

Comment: Thanks for looking into my post. No it wasn't copied as I am building a new component for the page.